# How to add js file for text in React js project?

Tags: reactjs

i has a lot text in project so i make a js file just for text , and add this file to index.html , when use this file have error but when inspect code i can see text ,

`faBundleForms.js`

```
const forms = {
    changeProfitDate: {
        note_1: 'user ',
        note_2: 'add '
    }
};
```

`add to index.html`

```
`<script  src="../static/faBundleForms.js" type="text/javascript">`</script>
```

`use to project`

```
<p>{forms.changeProfitDate.note_1}</p>
```

i have this error

```
 'forms' is not defined
```

Comment: may be the url of the js file specified in the src attribute is incorrect

Comment: no i can see file in source of project

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use global variables (which is a bad idea), you need to use `window.` before them, like this: `<p>{window.forms.changeProfitDate.note_1}</p>`

Comment: i use your recommend but i have this Error now:    "TypeError: Cannot read property 'changeProfitDate' of undefined"

Answer (score 0):

If you are using react the correct way seems to be something like this :
your text holding file :

```
export const text = ". . . lots of blah . . . "
export const text2 = ...
```

and you can import this file in your react project anywhere

```
import { text } from './yourTextFile'
const App = (props) => {
    return(
        <div>
            <p>{text}</p>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App
```

Comment: tax for idea but i has alot of text and repeat text alot , i need a better way